# Decrypt a /boot partition with grub from a passphrase stored in uefi flash

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, encryption

The current method to encrypt a /boot partition with grub is to ask for a passphrase to the user on the prompt. I would like to configure grub such that the passphrase is read from the uefi flash, like from one of the vars in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Can this be done, and how?

Comment: Curious: In that case, why bother to encrypt in the first place?

Comment: It's part of a specialized system setup. For this part we want to avoid that the disk can be removed and placed in another computer